# how to tell if an excel cell has conditional formatting applied using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a range of cells which have conditional formatting applied.

The aim was to visually separate the values with a positive, negative, and no change.

How can I use VBA to check if the cells have conditional formatting applied to them (such as color of the cell due to being a negative number)?

Comment: pnuts if you can tell me how to test for the presence of a style in a cell (when it has more than one, say "comma" and "Good") then I will spend the time to go through all the ones I have not responded to. Is there a filter I can apply in my account to see all those questions?

Answer (score 4):

See if the **Count** is zero or not:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox ActiveCell.FormatConditions.Count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Range.DisplayFormat to check if the conditional formatting is applied.
Put some data into column A and then use the below code example

```
Private Sub TestConditionalFormat()
Range("A:A").FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
Range("A:A").FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
Range("A:A").FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 13551615


Dim rCell       As Range
Dim i           As Long
For Each rCell In Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
If rCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
i = i + 1
End If
Next
MsgBox i & " :Cells Highlights for Duplicates."
End Sub
```

Comment: Range.DisplayFormat for the win. I wish I could mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

To use VBA to check if a cell has conditional formatting use the following code

```
Dim check As Range
Dim condition As FormatCondition
Set check = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Range("A1") 'this is the cell I want to check
Set condition = check.FormatConditions(1) 'this will grab the first conditional format
condition. 'an autolist of methods and properties will pop up and 
           'you can see all the things you can check here
'insert the rest of your checking code here
```

You can use parts of this code above with a for each loop to check all the conditions within a particular range.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying you have to check each type of conditional formatting individually? Can you just check for any? And then if it is there test for which one?

Comment: code camper -- what if you don't know what number conditional formatting you want to test for? For example If I need to know what color is in a cell I can write c = activecell.interior.color to find out, and then test for it elsewhere. How do I test for what conditional format I.e. red or green or what the color is that is applied to the cell?

Comment: @yoshiserry when it comes to conditional formatting you will have to test individually and know exactly what you are looking for. If you want to know what color is being applied by the conditional formatting try my code above with condition.Interior.Color if you give me a really specific example I will try to test some code for you.